# Вопрос-ответ эталон для закрывания дублями вопросов типа "помогите написать программу"

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, нытьё

**Проблема:**

Регулярно появляются вопросы вида: "ничего не умею, хочу написать программу, вот ТЗ, чё делать?". Они несут мало пользы сообществу и сайту и раздражают некоторых участников.
Один из примеров: [Нужна помощь по написанию небольшой программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/542273/2)

**Предложение:**

Написать эталонный вопрос-ответ, где в ответе будет пояснено как нужно задавать вопросы с пользой (да, оно есть в справке, но аббревиатура `RTFM` не на ровном же месте появилась). И закрывать новые подобные вопросы как дубль на этот.
Пример того, как это можно сделать я попытался набросать в помянутом уже вопросе: [исправленный вопрос-ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542277/17609)

Считаю это лучшим вариантом, по сравнению с посылом новичка в справку, т.к.:

- читать её, ИМХО, менее привычно чем вопрос-ответ
- ответ проще коллективно редактировать
- индексация поисковиками будет лучше
- закрывать как дубль удобнее, чем искать нужную статью в справке
- Плашка `ДУБЛЬ` гораздо заметнее одинокой ссылки в комментарии

В этот ответ можно суммировать эти четыре статьи из справки:

- [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- [Почему я вижу сообщение, что мой вопрос не отвечает стандартам качества?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)

Comment: Последнее что с этими вопросами стоит делать - это закрывать их как дубликат. Отметка дубликата автоматом [продлевает срок жизни закрытого вопроса с 9 дней до 30](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2293/).

Comment: @PashaPash, я с вами не согласен, по мне всё же дубль лучше... Но меня не поддержали, судя по голосам на ответах( А по ссылке я не нашёл про удаление дублей системой - они ж, вроде, не запрещены как таковые и вообще не подлежат удалению, т.к. являются лишь иной формулировкой к-л вопроса?

Comment: Кажется, кто-то примерно так и делает: _"I want some logics or even code to show it to me.The problem is just as the title says.Example: I enter n = 1234; I separate n to 1 2 and 3 4,sum 1 and 2 and then sum 3 and 4 in two variables.Then I compare the variables. I know how to separate the int,I know how to compare them,but I have no logic for the sum.How can I sum the two halves? Or even how can I separate those two halves?"_ - http://stackoverflow.com/q/38272058/4928642

Comment: @Qwertiy, что-то я не уловил вашей мысли(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, просто он уже вопрос поправил. Когда он мне попался, процитированный кусок был всем вопросом. Там не было даже кода. Зато был шикарный вопрос: я знаю, как считать число; я знаю, как поделить его на части; я знаю, как сравнить результаты; а как мне просуммировать половинки. Моя мысль была в том, что если задать все 4 таких вопроса, то можно будет собрать программу из готового кода. И это очень похоже на твой "эталонный" ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а-а-а) Теперь понятно. Правда, судя по голосам тут никому эта идея не нравится( Давно я не видел ситуаций, чтобы все так единодушно были неправы)

Answer (score 5):

Это не нужно, есть статья в справке. Надо направлять новичков туда.

Answer (score 0):

Отличное предложение, давно так надо было сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Авторов подобных вопросов не исправить ни справкой, ни дублем на эталон. Засим надо просто `минусовать`->`закрывать`->`удалять`